# UICollectionView scroll horizontal with dataSource from left to right

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and set horizontal.
And I see the datasource indexpath like this

```
page 1                  | page 2                     | page 3
item0 item2 item4 item6 | item8 item10 item12 item14 | item16 item18 item20 item22

item1 item3 item5 item7 | item9 item11 item13 item15 | item17 item19 item21 item23
```

I want to show like this

```
page 1                  | page 2                      | page 3
item0 item1 item2 item3 | item8 item9 item10 item11   | item16 item17 item18 item19

item4 item5 item6 item7 | item12 item13 item14 item15 | item20 item21 item22 item23
```

Have any idea to do this?

Comment: One option is to "transform" the data source... If you post enough code for a [mre], we can show you what to change.

Comment: If you haven't solved this yourself yet, we can help you. But... we need more information. What is a "page"? Are you using multiple **sections**? Is your data stored in a 1-dimensional or multi-dimensional array? Will you always have "8 items per section"?